# Parsing incomplete xml, maintaining capitalization

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an xml fragment that I need to parse. Here are the two ways I've tried to parse it using `lxml`:

```
s='''<Persons>
    <Person>
            <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
            <LastName>Tom</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
            <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>'''

>>> etree.fromstring(s)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag Person line 6, line 7, column 30

>>> html.fromstring(s)
<Element persons at 0x11fc49908>
```

However, I need to keep the case sensitivity of the tags -- I cannot put them all to lowercase as `html` does: however, using `etree` fails, so I'm forced to use the `html` parser.

How would I be able to keep the correct capitalization with the above issue? The tag needs to be `Persons` not `persons`.

I would like to stay within `lxml`, but so far the only solution I've found is using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
>>> bs4(s, 'xml')
<Persons>
...
```

Comment: Looks like you already answered your question? (`bs4`.)

Comment: I think you could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.pulldom.html as if you wanted as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still approach this with `lxml` by setting the ["recover" mode](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options) on:

> `recover` - try hard to parse through broken XML

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
root = etree.fromstring(s, parser=parser)
```

Demo:

```
In [2]: parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

In [3]: root = etree.fromstring(s, parser=parser)

In [4]: root
Out[4]: <Element Persons at 0x10aba9e18>
```